# How to inherit a pygame class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, pygame

When I run this code (this is the current entire code, ie, just 3 line):

```
import pygame
class sp(pygame.sprite):
    pass
```

I get:

`TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

I would like inherit this class to create some additional objects to it, as well as perform some of the already existing functions.

For example, rather than...

```
mysprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

I want...

```
mysprites = sp.Group()
```

How can I do this?

Comment: When you subclass `sprite` are you overriding the `__init__` method? If so can you show that code?

Comment: @101, I have now put the entire code, ie, just 3 lines...

Comment: Hang on, `sprite` is a module, not a class, so you can't subclass it. You could just import everything from `sprite` into a new module though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @101 mentioned in a comment, [`sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) is a `pygame` [sub] **module**, but is not itself a Python `class`. To do what you want, you'll need to derive your subclass from the `Sprite` class that module defines. This means using something along the lines below. (There's also an example in the [`pygame` documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) of a slightly different way of creating a `Sprite` subclass which you should probably take a look at.)

Note also that class names should have their initial letter Capitalized according to Naming Conventions section of the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), so I've fixed that as well.

```
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Sp(Sprite):
    pass
```

To answer the other part of your question where you're trying to use `sp.Group()`. The problem is what you're trying to do is just plain incorrect. `Group` is a separate "container" class that's also defined in the `pygame.sprite` module. It's primary purpose to group a bunch of `Sprite` class instances. It should be able to handle your `Sprite` subclass just fine. Below is more code showing how that can be done:

```
from pygame.sprite import Group, Sprite

class Sp(Sprite):
    pass

# Create a Group container instance and put some Sp class instances in it.
mygroup = Group()
sp1 = Sp()  # Create first instance of subclass.
mygroup.add(sp1)  # Put it in the Group (NOT via sp1.Group())

sp2 = Sp()  # Create another instance of subclass.
mygroup.add(sp2)  # Put it into the Group, too.
```

Comment: Ok, but how to execute a current object "Group"? `mysprites = Sp.Group()`

Comment: The latest update to my answer also addresses that aspect of your problem. Also see [How to use sprite groups in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851051/how-to-use-sprite-groups-in-pygame).