# Wall Collision doesnt work even though iteration of list is in place

Tags: python, pygame

my Wall Collision code doesnt work. I dont get any error message, the player just goes through the walls. This is my code:

```
def drawRect(x, y):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, [pxl(x), pxl(y), pxl(1), pxl(1)])
```

```
def drawLevel(level):
    global gameDrawn, wallsCoord
    x = y = 0

    wallsCoord = []

    walls = []

    ends = []

    
    
    if gameDrawn == False:
        screen.fill(WOODY)
        
        drawRect(1, 8)
        showTimer()
        
        for row in levels[level]:
            for col in row:
                if col == "W":
                    wall = Wall((x, y))
                    walls.append(wall)
                    wallsCoord.append((x, y))
                if col == "E":
                    end = End((x, y))
                    ends.append(end)
                if col == "P":
                    drawRect(1, 9)
                x += 80
            y += 80
            x = 0
        for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, wall.rect)
        for end in ends:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, end.rect)
    gameDrawn = True  
    return walls, ends

def drawPlayerPath(players):
    global wallsCoord
    for x, y in players:
        if (x, y) in wallsCoord:
            state = "gameover"
            init_state = True
        else:
            drawRect(x, y)

def getPlayerPath(players):
    global move_list, player_x, player_y
    player_x, player_y = players[0]
    for i in move_list:
        if i == 1:
            player_y -= 1
        elif i == 2:
            player_y += 1
        elif i == 3:
            player_x += 1
        elif i == 4:
            player_x -= 1
        players.append((player_x, player_y))
```

I dont really get, why it doesnt work since I already iterated the x and y values of the players list over the coordinates list of the walls.

Comment: Where is your collision detection?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add your walls in a sprite group and then you can iterate using the built-in collide method [pygame.Rect.colliderect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

Comment: Could you help me and tell me how to do that? I never created a sprite group

Comment: Check that previously answered question: [how-to-use-sprite-groups-in-pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851051/how-to-use-sprite-groups-in-pygame)

Comment: No! When using Sprites, `colliderect` ist not the correct function. Sprites and Groups have there own collision functions.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh, you are right I got confused offering solution using rect collision & mention sprites & spritegroup

Comment: But then the player rectangles must be sprites as well, am I right?

Comment: @ShawkyAhmed but can I use the sprite collision function to check if the sprite collides with a normal non-sprite rectangle?

Comment: I don't think you can, I suggest you just use the "walls" list to iterate over and check collision using pygame.Rect.colliderect(rect2), also you can check specific point for if collides with wall rect using pygame.Rect.collidepoint(x,y)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `global` statement, when you want to change a variable in global namespace within a function:

```py
def drawPlayerPath(players):
    global state, init_state    # <---
    for x, y in players:
        if (x, y) in wallsCoord:
            state = "gameover"
            init_state = True
        else:
            drawRect(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Sadly, it still doesn't work. So I have to find another solution.